# Allow Arbitrary Loads does not work in iOS 9.1 Simulator

Tags: ios9, nsurlsession

Trying to make NSURLConnection to a server on a VirtualBox VM on my local machine. The server is a test env with a self-signed RSA 2048-bit cert.

Apache SSL is configured thusly:

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
SSLCompression off
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/example/Web"
    SSLEngine On
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Wireshark shows that the client hello and server hello happen just fine. But we see in the `/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://example.com --verbose` that the client app rejects the server's cert because it is invalid (it's self-signed; I know it's invalid).

Supposedly you can add the "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to Info.plist to disable ATS in iOS 9, but I did this, and it does nothing. Client still rejects the self-signed cert.

Any ideas how I can make this work? I think maybe it's a problem specific to iOS simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow arbitrary loads overrides only the following:

- The prohibition on HTTP requests
- The key length and encryption type requirements for HTTPS

It has no effect on self-signed certificates.  To learn how to use self-signed certs, read [Overriding SSL Chain Validation Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html) on Apple's developer website.  Basically, you implement a custom authentication challenge handler, and if the protection space's authentication method is anything other than "server trust", tell the URL loading system to perform default handling.  Otherwise, either:

A.  Check the certificate's public key to ensure that it is yours, or

B.  Modify the trust object and evaluate it as follows:

1. Provide a copy of the certificate in your app.
2. Load the cert.
3. Add it as an anchor in the trust object
4. Evaluate the trust object,

The Apple doc provides detailed examples that should help.